# Trouble with htaccess dynamic redirects on IONOS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, ionos

I am on a Apache server and have created a site with php using a MySQL database on IONOS.

I want to redirect the URLs from /page.php?id=xxx to /page/xxx

I have written a .htaccess file and uploaded it into the root folder. It worked fine until yesterday. I have looked all IONOS support pages and different websites, but I can't find what's the issue.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I try to access the page with /page/xxx, it can't get the xxx id variable.

Comment: Looks like `Multiviews` are enabled on your server. Try adding this line `Options -Multiviews` to your htaccess to disable the directive then you will be able to use the `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thank you Amit. Indeed, I needed this instruction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteBase / is not required in DocumentRoot.  Also, your RewriteRule appears to be reversed:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php?id=(.*)$ /page/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: leading slash in `RewriteRule`'s pattern is not required when used in htaccess context. It should be removed otherwise the rule wont match the request. . `RewriteBase` is required because OP is using a relative path as substitution string. 
  Plus you cant match against query string in RewriteRule  You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: It still won't work. Op doesn't want to reditect the old URL to the new one. OP wants to map new URL to the old location.